# Smoothing formula for ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers

Tags: excel

Is there any reference materials to look up which specific smoothing formula is used for generating the lines of the `ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers`? Is it natural cubic splines with knots at marker points? I am trying to code the formula in stata replicating this smooth line. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what formula Excel uses for smoothing, but if you describe what you are ultimately trying to plot, it would be helpful.  Here's a Stata example for smoothing:

```
  sysuse auto, clear

        twoway scatter weight length, mcolor(*.8) || /*
        */  lpoly weight length, || lowess weight length /*
        */ , by(foreign)
```